# Internal Server Error from perl script solved by adding "-w" to the shebang line. But Why?

Tags: apache, perl, browser, server, internals

I spent hours and hours trying to fix an Internal Server Error on a perl program. I distilled the program down to the very simplest, and nothing would work. In fact, here's the entire program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<"thepage";
<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>
<p>help</p>
</body></html>
thepage
```

Couldn't get it to work. Permissions correct. Same directory where I have literally a hundred other scripts running constantly. httpd.conf fine. It runs from the command line when SSHing into the server. Error message says:

```
[Mon May 18 09:59:29 2020] [error] [client 98.190.183.148] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/data/www/facialsurgery/root/cgi-bin/test_print_2.pl' failed
[Mon May 18 09:59:29 2020] [error] [client 98.190.183.148] Premature end of script headers: test_print_2.pl
```

But I fixed it! By adding "-w" to the shebang line, so the line says:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
```

But I have, as I mentioned, many many programs running fine without the -w.
What can I do to trace this down more, so I don't eventually run into more trouble with more important programs?? Thanks so much for any insight in this.

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit.  What is the current filemode on that `.pl` file?  When you added `-w` did you also do a `chmod +x` on it?

Comment: Hi, Jim, I did not do chmod. The file was already 777, I know, too much permission, but I was debugging. All the directory permissions above were good, too. The file was in a directory where ~100 other scripts were operating. I went back and forth: I put in the "-w", and it worked. I took out the "-w", and it gave Server Error. Totally consistent. I'm baffled. As I mentioned, lot of other perl scripts did not have -w on shebang. It wasn't my habit.

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: Actually, this is the first I've heard of selinux, so I don't believe I do.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/data/www/facialsurgery/root/cgi-bin/test_print_2.pl' failed
```

This means that the web server (Apache) wasn't able to execute the script due to a permission error. (`13` is error number for `Permission denied`.) This has nothing to do with presence or absence of `-w`.<sup>[1]</sup>

First, determine as which user the web server (Apache) runs. For the remainder of this post, I'm going to assume it's the default, `www-data`.

Then, make sure the following file is readable (grants the `r` permission) and executable (`x`) by the `www-data` user (or its group):

- `/data/www/facialsurgery/root/cgi-bin/test_print_2.pl`

This includes making sure the following directories are accessible (`x`) by the `www-data` user (or its group):

- `/data/www/facialsurgery/root/cgi-bin`
- `/data/www/facialsurgery/root`
- `/data/www/facialsurgery`
- `/data/www`
- `/data`

If there's no problem with the permissions of those, you could also be running afoul or volume-wide limitations (e.g. `noexec` attribute on the value) or other security measures (e.g. SELinux restrictions)

---

1. I think that ancient systems used to treat everything after the shebang (`#!`) as the command to execute. On such a system, the kernel would try to execute the non-existent file `/usr/local/bin/perl -w`. But that would result in errno `2` (`No such file or directory`), and I don't believe any modern system does this.